# Angular, inject factory into provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having a little trouble doing this, I know you need to do it with `$get`, however the examples I find don't quite fall into the structure I need.

My provider looks like so

```
     .provider('moduleOb', function(){
    var modules = {};

    //outer closure to inject "this"
    function outerAddState(moduleObj) {

    };
    //outer function so we can push into module
    function modulePush(currentModule, name){

    }
    return {
        goState: function(name, stateName, options) {
                    //I need to use this function in here which injected from a factory
                     checkUrl.requestUrl();
        },
        moduleConstructor: function(name, cb) {

        },
        $get: function $get() {
            return this;
        }
    }   
})
```

So I'm just planting the get right now at the bottom as you can see. I need to be able to inject the `checkurl` factory somehow so I have access to it in `goState`. How would I format it so I can use the get to do so?

So if I separate the factory out into a separate module I can inject it with

```
   var injector = angular.injector(['urlParsing']);
    var checkUrl = injector.get('checkUrl')
```

inside the provider. However, the `checkurl` function has a dependency on `$location`. So the injector cannot find `$location` now --

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $locationProvider <- $location <- checkUrl
```

Can I inject the location provider too? Is this the best way of doing this?

Maybe with a get ($location)? Or maybe there is a better work around. Could use some help, this has been holding me up all day! Thanks for reading.

Edit2: After a few days of wrestling with this - I realize I'm just looking how to inject multiple modules ( a factory and it's dependancies of $log and $location) to a provider. The real reason being so I can let people set what I want them to set in the .config.

I have temporarily circumvented this by changing this provider to a factory and using the .run instead of the .config BUT I would still love to be able to use .config instead.